# JMeter '&' Character not Encoded as '&amp;' in the URL

Tags: regex, xml, xpath, jmeter, performance-testing

When request extracts a `URL variable` from `XML` document through `XPath Extractor` and `Regular Expression Extractor` it decodes the encoded characters in the extracted `URL`.

For example, the `URL` in the `XML` file:

```
<url>www.testing.com/test/request?parameter1=test1&amp;parameter2=test2</url>
```

The `&amp;` between the two `URL parameters` become `&` which affect my testing final results.

Is there any way to prevent special characters decoding in `JMeter`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally JMeter should not perform encoding and decoding of variables during extraction, the variable should be sent as is so most probably something is wrong with your test logic. You can double check the variable value using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination. See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more information on JMeter tests troubleshooting.

As a workaround you can explicitly tell JMeter to encode the variable using [__escapeHtml()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__escapeHtml) function like:

```
${__escapeHtml(${your_variable_here})}
```

[image: JMeter escapehtml]